# All Sites page not sorting correctly

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

On https://stackexchange.com/sites#name, I was looking for the Elementary OS SE page, but could not find it in the list. OK, try Technology... not seeing it there. Finally, I decided to do a Ctrl+F, and I found it - at the end of the list.

If sites are sorted by name, they should be *consistently* sorted by name. I'm assuming this is a bug, but with over 100 site names, I did not have a chance to look through them all.

[image]